# Remove /Index from url via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have my htaccess set up to strip the extension of my pages via the following code.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ /$1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [END]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

However if a user now follows a link to an index page (ie: example.com/index) it shows /index in the url which I would like to force remove. Ive seen a million examples on how to use htaccess to remove index.php or index.html but cant seem to find a way to incorporate those into my file since my urls dont have file extensions.

P.S. My experience in this area is very lacking, thoroughly commented examples appreciated.

Comment: "follows a link to an index page" - Presumably you're own internal links don't contain `index` and this is to fix 3rd party inbound links?

Comment: No, I use a generator and don't feel like going through and updating all the internal links.

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't implement a redirect in `.htaccess` to remove `index` since it will potentially slow your users, double the requests to your server and be detrimental to your SEO. The _only_ "practical" solution is to update your internal links.

Comment: My website is hosted in 165 different servers all over the world, speed and load isn't really an issue. Not to mention I really don't feel like doing that for over 100 websites every time I push an update and htaccess is a one time solution. But I appreciate your feedback and agree in most cases this is inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

# handle "file name extensions"
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,END]
# internally add file name extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /$1.php [END]

# handle "index" keyword
RewriteRule /?index/?$ /%1 [R=301,END]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /$1/index [END]
```

It matches the "index" keyword inside the `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{THE_REQUEST}` and adds the required internal rewriting.